# Android preferences in tab fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have three tabs (fragments) in my app, one of which should be a settings tab. I would like to use the AndroidX preference library for this settings tab.
I can open the settings tab and change settings, however once I have opened the settings tab once, the bottom navigation bar does not work anymore. When I close and restart the app the preferences have been saved. I *think* this is because `.replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragmentCompat())` replaces the entire activity including the bottom navigation bar.
How can I correctly load the preference fragment into the tab fragment?

SettingsFragment.kt (tab fragment)

```
package net.htlgrieskirchen.jheschl17.hypernote.ui.settings

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import net.htlgrieskirchen.jheschl17.hypernote.R

class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var view1: View

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragmentCompat())
            .commit()

        return view1
    }

}
```

SettingsFragmentCompat.kt (android boilerplate)

```
package net.htlgrieskirchen.jheschl17.hypernote.ui.settings

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import net.htlgrieskirchen.jheschl17.hypernote.R

class SettingsFragmentCompat : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the root element of the layout file corresponding to SettingsFragment to `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout` with id view_settings and changing `.replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragmentCompat())` to `.replace(R.id.view_settings, SettingsFragmentCompat())`.